# Is it possible to pass a SQLAlchemy table class name as an arg. in a Python function?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get familiar with SQLAlchemy, namely the ORM module. I've created a number of different table classes; `TableClass1`, `TableClass2`, `TableClass3`, etc. They all have a unique `ID` column. I'm using a MSSQL database.

I wanna to retrieve the max `ID` for each table, so I go ahead and do the following:

```
query1 = db.query(TableClass1.ID).order_by(TableClass1.ID.desc()).limit(1)
query2 = db.query(TableClass2.ID).order_by(TableClass2.ID.desc()).limit(1)
query3 = db.query(TableClass3.ID).order_by(TableClass3.ID.desc()).limit(1)
```

Connection settings are

```
engine = create_engine(
    f'mssql+pyodbc://{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?{DRIVER}')

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

db = SessionLocal()
```

**QUESTION**

However, this is sort of trivial. Is it possible to create some sort of callable method, where I can pass the names of the tables dynamically? I was thinking of something like:

```
def query_func(tablename):
    query = db.query(tablename.ID).order_by(tablename.ID.desc()).limit(1)
    return query
```

Comment: Sure but what is the variable `db`?  How is it assigned?

Comment: `db = SessionLocal()` - added to the question

Comment: So you are using FastAPI?  In that case the function code in the question should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'll use this to trigger some queries using FastAPI. Can I just pass a table class to the `query_func()` function?

Comment: Yes that should work fine if you are querying the entire table.  For a single attribute such as `id`, you'd want `db.query(getattr(ModelClass, 'id''))`.